# C# Vector maths questions

Tags: c#, math, vector

Im working in a screen coordinate space that is different to that of the classical X/Y coordinate space, where my Y direction goes down in the positive instead of up.

Im also trying to figure out how to make a Circle on my screen always face away from the center point of the screen.

If the center point of my screen is at x(200) y(300) and the point of my circle's center is at x(150) and y(380) then I would like to calculate the angle that the circle should be facing.

At the moment I have this:

```
        Point centerPoint = new Point(200, 300);
        Point middleBottom = new Point(200, 400);

        Vector middleVector = new Vector(centerPoint.X - middleBottom.X, centerPoint.Y - middleBottom.Y);

        Vector vectorOfCircle = new Vector(centerPoint.X - 150, centerPoint.Y - 400);

        middleVector.Normalize();
        vectorOfCircle.Normalize();

        var angle = Math.Acos(Vector.CrossProduct(vectorOfCircle, middleVector));

        Console.WriteLine("Angle: {0}", angle * (180/Math.PI));
```

Im not getting what I would expect.

I would say that when I enter in x(150) and y(300) of my circle, I would expect to see the rotation of 90 deg, but Im not getting that... Im getting 180!!

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: How does a circle face a direction? It has ∞-fold radial symmetry. Also, you keep changing the center of the circle. Is it (150, 380), (150, 400) or (150, 300)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ok, I think I got it now:

I read this article:

http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/index.htm

Which identified that I needed to use **Atan2** instead of **acos**

```
        Point centerPoint = new Point(200, 300);
        Point middleBottom = new Point(200, 400);

        Vector middleVector = new Vector(centerPoint.X - middleBottom.X, centerPoint.Y - middleBottom.Y);
        Vector vectorOfCircle = new Vector(centerPoint.X - 250, centerPoint.Y - 300);

        middleVector.Normalize();
        vectorOfCircle.Normalize();

        var angle = Math.Atan2(vectorOfCircle.Y, vectorOfCircle.X) - Math.Atan2(middleVector.Y, middleVector.X);

        Console.WriteLine("Angle: {0}", angle * (180/Math.PI));
```

Comment: +1 Right! Atan2 is such a useful function, and nearly no one knows about it.

Comment: I prefer `var angle = Math.Acos(dotProduct)`. With little background in math, it's easier to understand and more efficient (if you are picky). Subtractions is not commutative, which means you get negative and/or unnormalized >2pi angles when using Math.Atan2 (which often has to be checked for). If this is not what you want, i.e. you always want the smallest angle between two vectors, use the dot product.

Comment: As I see now, actually using the dot product in your example makes no sense, because for things like facing I would rely on negative angles. So `var angle = Math.Asin(crossProduct)` would provide you the signed angle better than the Math.Atan2 solution, because you don't have to check for angles >2pi.

Answer (score 1):

One remark:

The cos-sinus function is used in the dot product.
Cross product uses sinus.

Comment: You use Acos instead of Asin or wrong type of vector product in Your code. Look carefully at the line: var angle = Math.Acos(Vector.CrossProduct(vectorOfCircle, middleVector));

Answer (score 0):

No, that is correct. The zero angle is from origo (centerPoint) out to the right. As the circle is to the left of origo, then angle is 180 degrees.